# Bug in drawInRect in iOS 5.1

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have some problems with drawing images on context.

Apps start crashing on iOS 5.1 on 3gs and 4s devices(another didn't tested) while trying to downsize png image with transparent area. Images for test attached.

Steps to Reproduce:
Try run code on iOS 5.1

```
UIImage *imageN = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oval_1.png"]; // oval_1.png actual size (1936, 2592)
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(90, 90));
[imageN drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1900, 2592)];    
UIImage * newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Expected Results:
Receive downsized image ((UIImage*)newImage)

Also when I try apple's example https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LargeImageDownsizing/Introduction/Intro.html
with my image. It crashes on 3gs and works on 4s.

Conditions for 99% app crash:

- image has transparent area.
- image bigger than devices screen.
- image must be drawn smaller size, than images actual size

image for tests:

http://orbit-soft-minsk.com/oval_1.png

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: Have you identified the problem?  I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I found somewhere in docs that drawing will not work correct with images that exceed 2048 pixels wide or high on devices older than the iPad 2 or iPhone 4S

Comment: I've also got this problem, it crashes on `CGContextDrawImage()`

Comment: I can confirm that this is a bug specific to iOS 5.1 - it works in iOS6 and prior releases. Lost 5 hours of my evening trying to figure out why it was crashing...